# How to display the sorting arrow on page load and during sort in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I am displaying a GridView and sorting it and displaying an image per sorting on the header.

When the page first loads I do not see the arrow next to the row that I am sorting. Only after a click I see the arrow. When I click on another row to sort, it sorts correctly but the arrow is displayed on the previous sorted row. Only after the second click on the existing row does the arrow disappears from the previous sorted row to the current row.

How can I modify the code so,

- On page load the image is displayed next to the header that is sorted
  by direction?
- How to display the image next to the header on first click, rather
  than on the second click?

Comment: Are you trying this(see the not eual to operator instead of equal to), if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() != "Desc")
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Asc";
        }

Comment: No, it is correct. I am checking if it's already in DESC then do ASC otherwise do DESC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are changing the sort direction after loading the data.

Try changing your grid sorting event like this

```
ViewState["sortExp"] = e.SortExpression;
PullData(e.SortExpression, sortOrder);
```

Comment: Awesome, that solved the clicking issue. Any idea for the on page load event

Comment: I changed the !Page.Postback code to `ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Desc";
ViewState["sortExp"] = "Task Name";PullData("Task Name", "Desc");` and everything is working now. Answer accepted. Simple yet wasn't able to solve without an intervention :/

Comment: If you can't solve it for 5 minutes of thinking use a debugger :)

Comment: Tried debugging but it was more of a logic issue :)